Is it possible to apply kolmogorov smirnov for class interval data?
Let`s suppose i have the data bellow, how should i calculate the ECDF's and the how should i calculate the D critical value? I'm trying to follow the steps from https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~dias/Lecture%2013.pdf , i'm not even sure if i can apply the Kolmogorov Smirnov test using this data.



age
expectated deaths
observed deaths




<= 30 years
1
1


31 - 40 years
1
2


41 - 50 years
2
4


51 a 60 years
8
6


61 a 70 years
12
4


71 a 80 years
8
5


> 80 years
7
4



There's also this source which says "The test may be carried out on samples of any size, provided the samples are independent, and sample data is of ordinal scale.". But i don't know if it fits in the case. I also tried in R software but as i said before, am i able to use this data?
> ks.test(c(1, 1, 2, 8, 12, 8, 7), c(1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4))

    Exact two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  dados_ks1$esp and dados_ks1$obs
D = 0.57143, p-value = 0.1434
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

